# How to get count by order in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collections name `listings` and `moods`.

`listings` sample:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3"),
    "name": "Hotel Radisson Blu",
    "moods": [
      ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439010"),
      ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")
    ]
}
```

`moods` sample:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    "name": "Sports"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439010"),
    "name": "Spanish Food"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439009"),
    "name": "Action"
}
```

I need this record.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    "name": "Sports",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439010"),
    "name": "Spanish Food",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439009"),
    "name": "Action",
    "count": 0
}
```

I need this type of record. I have no idea about aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to join collection `listings`
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) pipeline to check `moods` _id in `listings` field `moods` array

```
db.moods.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "listings",
      "as": "count",
      let: { id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": { "$in": ["$$id", "$moods"] }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to add `count` on the base of [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of array `count` that we got from above lookup

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      count: { $size: "$count" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KDw4Mkjln0Q)

Answer (score -1):

did this work:

```
db.collection.aggrate().count()
```

Try to combine the functions, it might work.

Comment: Any idea? How can I use with my collections?

Comment: moods is the name of your collection and so you could try db.moods.aggragate().count() giving your parameters as per requirements.